# error 43 in pandoc: render Rmd with rmarkdown include LaTeX qtree

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to produce a tree diagram in a Rmd file I expect to look like this:

[image]

Using **rmarkdown**'s `render` function.

But get an ***error 43*** I do not know how to interpret.  How can I get the pdf to render?  What's causing the error?

## Rmd file

```
---
title: "testtree"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{qtree}
output:
    pdf_document
---

\Tree [.S [.NP LaTeX ] [.VP [.V is ] [.NP fun ] ] ]

Success
```

## Error message

```
> rmarkdown::render("testtree.Rmd", "all")


processing file: testtree.Rmd
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: testtree.knit.md

"C:/Users/trinker/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS testtree.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output testtree.pdf --template "C:\R\R-3.2.2\library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.14.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
! Paragraph ended before \doanode was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.90 

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Users/trinker/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS testtree.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output testtree.pdf --template "C:\R\R-3.2.2\library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.14.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43 
>
```

The following .Rnw document compiles successfully:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

Here is a code chunk.

\Tree [.S a [.NP {\bf b} c ] d ]

You can also write inline expressions, e.g. $\pi=\Sexpr{pi}$, and \Sexpr{1.598673e8} is a big number.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\tree` command works in a Rnw file with knitr.

Comment: it means that LaTeX failed to create a PDF... try your inline TeX with `pdflatex` first...

Comment: you can use `keep_tex: true` as an output option to troubleshoot. It seems that there are two problems: 1. your expression does not work in a regular tex file for me. I have to add new lines after each closing bracket and 2. pandoc treats the last two closing brackets as literal strings and encloses them in { : `{]} {]}` instead of `] ]`.

Comment: @scoa Thanks.  Great leads... The expression works in an Rnw for me and after I turn `{]}` into `]` in the .tex `keep_tex: true` nakes the file runs.  How can I prevent pandoc from interpreting `]` as `{]}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandoc turns the last two closing brackets `] ]` as `{]} {]}`, a behavior you can see if you use output option `keep_tex: true`. I am not sure whether this is a bug, you should ask this on the pandoc mailing-list or [file a report](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues).

A quick fix is to use [pandoc's ability to ignore the code inside an environment](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-tex) and surround your command with a dummy environment:

```
---
title: "testtree"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{qtree}
   - \newenvironment{dummy}{}{}
output:
    pdf_document:
      keep_tex: true
---

\begin{dummy}
\Tree [.S [.NP LaTeX ] [.VP [.V is ] [.NP fun ] ] ]
\end{dummy}

Success
```

Comment: That's terrific.  Didn't know you could do that.  Thank you.