# How to force passing of % comment tags as comments in a latex file when editing markdown

Tags: markdown, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

When converting markdown files to latex files, pandoc makes sure all % characters remain as regular `%` characters by automatically escaping them (`\%`). My workflow requires me to pass the `%TC:ignore` and `%TC:endignore` tags to the markdown so that I can use `texcount` utility. Is there a way to force passage of `%` as plain old `%` signs without being escaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two workarounds.

I explained the first one in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524968/error-43-in-pandoc-render-rmd-with-rmarkdown-include-latex-qtree/33547410#33547410). We can use pandoc's ability to pass raw latex if it is in an environment. We define a new environment that does nothing and pass the comment there. It is quite ugly, but it works:

```
---
header-includes:
   - \newenvironment{dummy}{}{}
---
\begin{dummy}
%TC:ignore
\end{dummy}
```

The second one is to write a filter to transform some strings as `RawInline` of type `latex` rather than actual strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, RawInline

def comments(k, v, f, meta):
    if k == 'Str' and v in ['%TC:ignore','%TC:endignore']:
        return RawInline('latex', v)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    toJSONFilter(comments)
```

Save this as `comments.py` and run as `pandoc myfile.md -o myfile.tex --filter comments.py`. You need a python installation and the library `pandocfilters` (`pip install pandocfilters` should do it).

The advantage of this solution is that it keeps the input file clean. But you need to add all the strings you want to escape this way in the filter, which can be cumbersome if you have various types of comments.